# Why is custom 404 PHP error page only working online for URLs where non-existing directories are involved, no matter if the file exists or not?

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

My custom 404 error page only seems to work online for URLs that contain directories that don't exist. If I only have a non-existing file (in an existing directory tree), then I get - instead of my desired custom 404 page - a blank page with "File not found". Seems like, no matter if I have a non-existing file or an existing file in my URL, I only get my custom 404 page when there is a non-existing / misspelled directoy somewhere in the URL. Offline, on Xampp it works fine, though. Can anybody point me in the right direction as to what I might be doing wrong?

This is what my ".htaccess" looks like, which I put in my root directory along with my custom error page:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 401 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 405 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 408 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 502 /error404.php
ErrorDocument 504 /error404.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Update: It seems that the cause of my problems is the file extention ".php". If I call files that don't exist with an extention ".php" I get "File not found". If I use the extention ".html" in my query my custom 404 error page works alright.

[example with html extention](https://www.haushalts-geld.de/dsvdsvds.html)

[example with php extention](https://www.haushalts-geld.de/dsvdsvds.php)

Technial Support from my hosting provider suggests to have a look at my configuration where I include extentions. I am not sure where I should look to be honest. Maybe someone can narrow this down?

I have to further test this, but the following lines in my .htaccess file might do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteRule ^.+\.php$ /non_existant_file
```